# Recycler View not getting Displayed (in Card View) for weather app. Tried solutions from Stack Overflow. Nothing is Working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to develop an application in android with the help of Geeks for Geeks tutorials. I am still learning how to develop android apps. It is a simple weather app where I need to display forecast in recycler view with the help of card view. The code is as shown from the video, but still the recycler view is not getting displayed. API url is also working. There is no error shown.
App Permissions - Location and Internet  (Added in Manifest)

It was a request to please help me out with this issue.
Please do reply.

Main_Activity.java file is just a splash screen.

Main_Activity2.java

```
package com.androidp.wheatherapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.

app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.VoiceInteractor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout rlayout;
    private ProgressBar pbar;
    private TextView cityNameiv;
    private TextView temp;
    private TextView condi;
    private EditText editCity;
    private ImageView IVsearch,ivicon,backIV;
    private RecyclerView recyclerWeather;
    private ArrayList<WeatherModal> weatherModalArrayList;
    private weatherAdapter adapter;
    private String cityName;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private int PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        rlayout = findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
        pbar = findViewById(R.id.pbar);
        cityNameiv = findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        temp = findViewById(R.id.temp);
        condi = findViewById(R.id.condi);
        editCity = findViewById(R.id.editCity);
        ivicon = findViewById(R.id.ivicon);
        IVsearch = findViewById(R.id.IVsearch);
        recyclerWeather = findViewById(R.id.recyclerWeather);
        backIV = findViewById(R.id.backIV);


        weatherModalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new weatherAdapter(this,weatherModalArrayList);
        recyclerWeather.setAdapter(adapter);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity2.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_CODE);
        }


        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        cityName = getCityName(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        getweatherInfo(cityName);

        IVsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String city = editCity.getText().toString();
                if(city.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Please Enter City Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    cityNameiv.setText(cityName);
                    getweatherInfo(city);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE){
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Allow Permissions",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getCityName(double longitude, double latitude){
        String cityName = "Not Found";
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,10);

            for (Address adr : addresses){
                if(adr!= null){
                    String city = adr.getLocality();
                    if(city!= null && !city.equals("")){
                        cityName = city;
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("TAG","User City not found");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return cityName;
    }


    private void getweatherInfo(String cityName){
        String url="https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=deadad1688ef46f8929170126213010&q="+ cityName+"&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no";

        //cityNameiv.setText(cityName);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity2.this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //weatherModalArrayList.clear();

             try {
                 String temperature = response.getJSONObject("current").getString("temp_c");
                 temp.setText(temperature + " °c");

                 int isDay = response.getJSONObject("current").getInt("is_day");
                 String condition = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("text");
                 String condiicon = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                 Picasso.get().load("https:".concat(condiicon)).into(ivicon);

                 condi.setText(condition);
                 if(isDay==1){
                     Picasso.get().load("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/929229.jpg").into(backIV);
                 }
                 else {
                     Picasso.get().load("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/929229.jpg").into(backIV);
                 }

                 JSONObject forecastObj = response.getJSONObject("forecast");
                 JSONObject forecast0 = forecastObj.getJSONArray("forecastday").getJSONObject(0);

                 JSONArray hourarray = forecast0.getJSONArray("hour");

                 for(int i=0; i < hourarray.length();i++){
                     JSONObject hourobj = hourarray.getJSONObject(i);
                     String time = hourobj.getString("time");
                     String temp1 = hourobj.getString("temp_c");
                     String img = hourobj.getJSONObject("time").getString("icon");
                     String wind = hourobj.getString("wind_kph");
                     weatherModalArrayList.add(new WeatherModal(time,temp1,img,wind));
                 }
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Please enter valid city Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pbar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rlayout"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/backIV"
            android:src="@color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/cityName"
            android:text="City Name"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/idlin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cityName"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editCity"
                android:layout_margin="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="4.5"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:hint="Enter City"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/purple_200"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/IVsearch"
                android:src="@drawable/search"/>

        </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/temp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="70dp"
                android:text="23"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/idlin"
                />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ivicon"
            android:layout_below="@id/temp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/condi"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Condition"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/ivicon"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Today's Wheather Forecast"
            android:layout_above="@id/recyclerWeather"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerWeather"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

weatherAdapter.java

```
package com.androidp.wheatherapp;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;


public class weatherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<weatherAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<WeatherModal> weatherModalArrayList;

    public weatherAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WeatherModal> weatherModalArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.weatherModalArrayList = weatherModalArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public weatherAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.weather_rv,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull weatherAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        WeatherModal modal = weatherModalArrayList.get(position);
        holder.idTemperature.setText(modal.getTemperature() + "°c");
        Picasso.get().load("https:".concat(modal.getIcon())).into(holder.idCondition);
        holder.wind.setText(modal.getWindSpeed()+"km/hr");
        SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat output =  new SimpleDateFormat("hh:min aa");
        try {
            Date t = input.parse(modal.getTime());
            holder.idTime.setText(output.format(t));
        }catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return weatherModalArrayList.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView idTemperature, idTime, wind;
        private ImageView idCondition;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {


            super(itemView);

            idCondition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idCondition);
            idTemperature = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTemperature);
            wind = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextview);
            idTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTime);


        }
    }
}
```

WeatherModal.java

```
package com.androidp.wheatherapp;

public class WeatherModal {
    private String Time;
    private String Temperature;
    private String icon;
    private String windSpeed;

    public WeatherModal(String time, String temperature, String icon, String windSpeed) {
        Time = time;
        Temperature = temperature;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }

    public String getTemperature() {
        return Temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(String temperature) {
        Temperature = temperature;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(String windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }


}
```

weather_rv.xml - Card View

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card_bag"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/idTime"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="TIME"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/idTemperature"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="20"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/idTime"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/idTemperature"
            android:id="@+id/idCondition"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/idCondition"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/idTextview"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

ScreenShot Of App
The recycler view is to be displayed below Today's Weather Forecast

[image]

Comment: There is no space "below Today's Weather Forecast".

Comment: android:text="Today's Wheather Forecast"
android:layout_above="@id/recyclerWeather"    and its actually working fine in the video

Comment: If any one has any idea about it please let me know. I am trying to find  the issue but I am not able to figure it out. Please Do Reply

Comment: LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
adapter = new weatherAdapter(this,weatherModalArrayList);
recyclerWeather.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); 
        recyclerWeather.setAdapter(adapter);

Try this.

Comment: Already Tried. Still not working. Has just added horizontal instead of Vertical